# Is there a loss in quality while using Imagemagick's "convert -append ..." to stitch

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

(continuation of title) ... multiple images - from a grid layout - into one large complete image?

The reason for my asking is that I am using, i.e. have downloaded from Imagemagick's site, Download section, ***ImageMagick-7.0.7-26-portable-Q16-x86.zip***.
x86 meaning it is for 32-bit OS, Q16 permitting to read or write 16-bit image without losing precision, and static meaning it is statically compiled (that is of less importance).

***I am working with a series of images, each but the boundary ones (that can vary in size in one dimension) of size 256x256, 96 dpi and 24 bit depth.***

If using the above tool, for stiching those images together,

```
 convert -append 6-0-0.jpg 6-1-0.jpg ... 6-_-0.jpg
```

Is there a loss of quality, ***considering they have 24 bit depth and Imagemagick only supports images up to 16 bit depth? Or do I have it wrong? Can someone elaborate on the said "bit depth" to explain the restrictions of Imagemagick tool?***

Comment: I think you misunderstand depth. 24-bit depth is 8-bits per 3 channels. So 3*8=24. You can also have 16-bits per channel so that the total is 16*3=48 bits.  You have several issues. The first is that IM 7 used magick rather than convert. Second, your syntax is not correct. Read the input images right after magick and then do the -append operations. Lastly, you will lose some quality, since your input images are JPGs, which have lossy compression. So every time you read and then write to jpg, some loss in quality will occur even if the "quality" value remains the same.

Comment: The Q16 version of ImageMagick can handle 16-bits per channel. Your data is 8-bits per channel so you will be fine. It is only called 24-bit because there are 3 such channels, one of red data, one of green data and one of blue data. Your command should be of the format `magick image1.jpg image2.jpg ... -append result.jpg`

Comment: @fmw42 - Hi, thanks for answering. I got the part about bit depth, but lost you in magick vs convert. What is the difference between the two? I tried using them both, and the result seems to be identical. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Mark, thanks for answering! What is the difference between convert and magick for the operation I am doing? I tried using magick 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -append 123.jpg and the result seems to be the same as with convert (as in the question)?

Comment: It is probably identical in the specific case you are currently using. In general though, if you use `magick` you get access to new, version 7 capabiities whereas you do not with the legacy `convert` invocation. An example would be that v7 expands `fx` expressions in parameters whereas v6 did not.